# UISplitview Controller not rotating in iOS 4.3 and 5.x. It works fine on iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have created a new project from template, using Master-Detail Application template in XCode 4.6. The project was created for iOS 6.x by default by XCode 4.6.

I changed the Deployment Target to iOS 4.3 and changed .xib files so that they work with iOS 4.3.

When I run this on iOS 4.3/5.x the app remains in Portrait mode and does not rotate.
Also the popover(for masterViewController) does not appear in portrait mode.

Please note the this happens only on iOS 4.3 and 5.x. It works fine on iOS 6.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dealing with the ios 6 below version's orientation you need to handle

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

method.

The delegate methods which we have for ios 6 orientation won't fire in earlier versions.